# Scroll page from within cross domain iframe 

Tags: facebook, iframe, scroll

Situation: I have a page with an iframe, which contains a form. But the iframe is longer than a screen page and the user has to scroll down to submit it. But it loads just the contents of the iframe, so it'll be scrolled by the same amount before submitting the page. I want to be at the top of the page. But since the user scrolled the facebook page and not the iframe, I cannot use scrollTo (not allowed for cross domain iframes).

Question: Is it possible submit the form to facebook to reload the entire page and still gives me access to the form data?

Comment: question is unclear, is it page tab app or canvas or your independent website? maybe a screenshot will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely sure if this is what you're asking, but if it's an iframe app you can use FB.Canvas.scrollTo to control the main Facebook page position. You can either call it selectively or you can put code like this in the `<head>` section of every page:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function() { FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0); }
</script>
```

That way every time you load a new page in your iframe, the main page will return to the top.